# Comparing dataframes date column values in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare 2 date columns between 2 dataframes.

I have df1 and df2 and if the date in df1 > df2 do some stuff.

But when I tried

```py
if df1['date'] > df2['date']:
        print('some stuff')
```

It returns an error:

> ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Check the dates in both dfs are the same dtype = datetime64[ns]
looks like 2019-01-10.

Tried to reset indexes:

```py
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = df2.reset_index(drop=True)
```

But it didn't help

No idea why it happens like this :(

## Update

I also tried to set max date in df1 as a variable and compare df2['date'] with it, but it throws another error

```py
max_date_df1 = df1['date'].max()

df2['date'] > max_date_df1
```

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Are the DataFrames of the same length? You could join them and then use something like `.loc()`

Comment: @Carsten no, they are different. I want to check the dates because it is a script of updating a database and I can't join the dfs because it will duplicate values :(

Comment: You shouln't use series comparison like this because `df1['date'] > df2['date']` returns a series of boolean and not a single boolean meaning Python can't really work with that. Also if the DataFrames have different size the comparaison is weird, what do you really want to compare ?

Comment: @SmileyProd in fact I just wanna check the date in a dataframe 1. If the last date in dataframe1 is less than today, then update it with values from dataframe 2  if no, do nothing

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the value you're comparing won't change in the case of one dataframe since you've tried using max_date. You could try using `np.where` as follows:

```
import numpy as np
max_date = df1['date'].max()
df2['new_field'] = np.where(df2['date'] < max_date, <Val if True>, <Val if False>)
```

Let me know if I'm understanding you problem wrong.